# PDF file not downloading, JPG file ok

Tags: python, python-3.10, windows-11

I recently re-activated a python project from last year. It still worked. I recently bought a new computer and upgraded to Windows 11. I also updated my Pycharm to the latest and updated to python 10.1. The program no longer works. Which update is the culprit?
Below shows the essence of the code which does not work. I can successfully download .jpg files but not .pdf files.

```
from wand.image import Image
file1 = 'U:/Image Files/Bonnie Dundee.jpg'
print(file1)
img1 = Image(filename=file1, resolution=300)
file2 = 'U:/Image Files/Frosty Morning.pdf'
print(file2)
img2 = Image(filename=file2, resolution=300)
```

The error trace is:

```
C:\Users\jradc\PycharmProjects\Scratch\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/jradc/PycharmProjects/Scratch/main.py
U:/Image Files/Bonnie Dundee.jpg
U:/Image Files/Frosty Morning.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jradc\PycharmProjects\Scratch\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    img2 = Image(filename=file2, resolution=300)
  File "C:\Users\jradc\PycharmProjects\Scratch\venv\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 9144, in __init__
    self.read(filename=filename)
  File "C:\Users\jradc\PycharmProjects\Scratch\venv\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 9815, in read
    self.raise_exception()
  File "C:\Users\jradc\PycharmProjects\Scratch\venv\lib\site-packages\wand\resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.DelegateError: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin64c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300" -dPrinted=false  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/jradc/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-xx4FiylIV-id96p7igp2OZkQb3jLaJ_t%d" "-fC:/Users/jradc/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-wcsbcSOqVJ1dFFk0CAU_gvAVIYrZi1Ut" "-fC:/Users/jradc/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-1GWjBArMZle6Xrv-HTjtyKzCqE1Csf8H"' (The system cannot find the file specified.
) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/516

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone point to what I need to change to get this back to working?

I corrected the file extension.

Comment: You have the file name end with `.pfd`, did you mean `.pdf`?

Comment: Yea, in the Python code in file2 variable in the value

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the system could not find `gswin64c.exe`.
py-Wand uses that to convert PDF to PNG.

Check that [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/index.html) (you probably want the AGPL release) is installed and in your `Path`.

In the "explorer", search for `gswin64c.exe` and note the directory where it is.

Then look for "Environment variables" in the start menu and verify that the aforementioned directory is in the `Path`. If not, edit the path and add it.

Comment: ghostscript is in the Python Interpreter listing and shows up in the site-Packages on Pycharm. Does it need to be somewhere else?

Comment: Its location needs to be in the environment variable `PATH`, so that py-Wand can call it without specifying its location.

Comment: gswin64c.exe does not show up at all! I will do some digging.

Comment: I found gswin32c.exe in an AGPL download and added it to my path. All works well now. Thanks.